# .ebextensions with CodePipeline and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I started working on my first CodePipeline with node.js app which is hosted on github. I would like to create simple pipe as follow:

1. Github repo triggers pipe
2. Test env (Elastic Beanstalk app) is built from S3 .zip file
3. Test env runs `npm test` and `npm lint`
4. If everything is OK then QA env (another EB app) is built

For above pipe I've created `.config` files under `.ebextensions` directory:

1. I would like to use `npm install --production` for QA and PROD env, but it seems that EC2 can't find node nor npm. I checked logs and EC2 triggered `npm install` by default in temporary folder, then it fails on my first script and app catalogue is always empty.

`container_commands:
  install-dev:
    command: "npm install"
    test: "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"TEST\" ]"
    ignoreErrors: false
  install-prod:
    command: "npm install --production"
    test: "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" != \"TEST\" ]"
    ignoreErrors: false`

2. Is it posible to run unit tests and linting without jenkins?

`container_commands:
  lint:
    command: "npm run lint"
    test: "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"TEST\" ]"
    ignoreErrors: false
  test:
    command: "npm run test"
    test: "[ \"$NODE_ENV\" = \"TEST\" ]"
    ignoreErrors: false`

I set `NODE_ENV` for each Elastic Beanstalk instance. No matter what I will do every time my pipe fails because of `npm is not recognized`, but how is it possible if I'm running 64bit Amazon Linux with node.js ? What's more I cannot find any examples about CodePipeline with node.js in AWS Docs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you incorporated CodeBuild into your pipeline?

You should

1) Create a pipeline whose source is your github account. Go through the setup procedure so that commits on a particular branch trigger the Codepipeline

2) Create a test stage in your Codepipeline which leverages the CodeBuild service. In order to run your Node tests, you might need to provide a configured build environment. And you probably also need to provide a build spec file that specifies the tests to run etc.

3) Assuming that the test stage passes, you can determine if the pipeline continues to another stage which is linked to an elasticbeanstalk app environment which supports the Node platform. These environments are purely for artifacts that have passed testing, so I see no need to have the .ebextensions commands written above.

Have a read of what CodeBuild can do to help you run tests for Node,

https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You point me in the right direction. CodeBuild is a golden mean between Jenkins and other providers. I did manage to configure everything :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using AWS for CI/CD, you can use [CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/). However, Github provides a great feature called [Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) for running Unit Tests, which I find much simpler than AWS. Anyway, I will walk you through both examples:

**Using AWS for running Unit Tests**

Essentially, you could create a new stage into your CodePipeline, and configure the CodeBuild for running Unit Tests, e.g.

First, add a buildspec.yml file in the root folder of your app so you can use the following example:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10  
    commands:
      - echo Installing Mocha globally...
      - npm install -g mocha
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing dependencies...
      - npm install
      - npm install unit.js
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Run Unit Tests and so on 
      - npm run test
      - npm run lint
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`

# THIS IS OPTIONAL
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.js
    - package.json
    - src/app/*
    - node_modules/**/*
```

You can find everything you need in the BackSpace Academy, this course is **for free**:
[AWS DevOps CI/CD - CodePipeline, Elastic Beanstalk and Mocha](https://www.udemy.com/course/nodejs-cicd-aws-codepipeline-codebuild-mocha-zero-to-hero)

**Using Github for running Unit Tests**

You could create your custom actions using Github, it will automatically  set up everything you need in your root folder, e.g.

[image: Github Actions]

After choosing the appropriate workflow, it will automatically generate a folder/file ".github > workflow > nodejs.yml".

So it will look like this:

```
name: Node CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm test
      env:
        CI: true
```

I hope you could find everything you need in this answer. Cheers